# Reflash a cisco 1600 router or is it good for anything?

Tags: cisco, router, flash

I have some old cisco 1600 (1604 mostly) series routers (10BT ethernet), most of them have flash cards in them - for example, one has an IOS 11.1 written on it.    Some have no WIC cards, though one has a T1 DSU/CSU card.

I was wondering if there is any use for these for possibly:

1. As a vpn client for a small (< 10 users) remote site to a cisco asa or pix?   This would not be the firewall/router for their internet though.
2. Maybe it can be flashed somehow similar to the famous NSLU2 or other devices that can be flashed with flavors of linux or otherwise and used for some other purpose - maybe as a serial to ethernet gateway?

Any other ideas or are these junk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll have much luck flashing them.  Why not sell them or donate them?  Old routers are very useful for those doing their Cisco certifications.

Comment: defo. to alot of people these things are still super useful.